# Random Number in Octave

Tags: matlab, random, octave

I need to generate a random number that is between .0000001 and 1, I have been using rand(1) but this only gives me 4 decimal points, is there any other way to do this generation?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that 4 decimal points is real precision and it is not rounding during display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Octave docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Terminal-Output.html):

> By default, Octave displays 5 significant digits in a human readable form (option ‘short’ paired with ‘loose’ format for matrices).

So it's probably an issue with the way you're *printing* the value rather than the value itself.

That same page shows the other output formats in addition to `short`, the one you may want to look in to is `long`, giving 15 significant digits.

And there is also the `output_precision` which can be set as per [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Matrices.html#doc-output_precision):

```
old_val = output_precision (7)
disp (whatever)
old_val = output_precision (old_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the output_precision to 7 and it should be ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the output precision won't help though because the number can still be less than .0000001 in theory but you will only be displaying the first 7 digits. The simplest way is:

```
req=0;
while (req<.0000001)
 req=rand(1);
end
```

It is possible that this could get you stuck in a loop but it will produce the right number. To display all the decimals you can also use the following command:

```
format long
```

This will show you 15 decimal places. To switch back go:

```
formay short
```